# How can I see which language type will result from the union or intersection of different language types?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I have to decide which language type will result from the union of a type-2 (context-free) and a type-3 (regular) language.

Is there a way or rule to decide this for all language types?

Comment: Asking for a general method applying to all language types is unlikely
to be a good question. A language can be any set of strings, however
defined. A language type (or family), for lack of a more precise
definition is just a set of languages, however defined. So, when you
want something that applies to all language types, you want to find
very, very general rules about objects you know essentially nothing
about. Though there are very general theorems, what you are asking is
not very likely to happen. It would be better to ask for general rules applying to many types of languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a minor point of terminology. In the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy), type-2
languages are the context-free family, not the context-sensitive one. I do
not know which you meant.

In general, the terminology used is *family* of language rather than
*type* of language. The fact that the application of some operation
$\diamond$ applied to languages in families $\mathcal F_i$ always
gives a language in the family $\mathcal F$ is called a closure
property.

As stated by Hendrik Jan in [his answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40728/how-can-i-see-which-language-type-will-result-from-the-union-or-intersection-of/40731#40731), there are no general rules to
determine closure properties and they can vary a lot. To complement
his examples, context-free (type 2) languages are not closed under
intersection:  the intersection of two context-free languages may not
be a context-free language. However, the intersection or union of a
context-free language with a regular language is always context-free.
(proving it is an excellent exercise).

Since you are ambiguous as to what family of languages you are interested in,
it so happens that the context-sensitive languages are also closed
under union or intersection with regular languages.

Actually, many (most ?) interesting families of languages are closed
under union or intersection with regular languages.

Though there are no general rules for proving it, there are many other
operations one may consider on the languages of a family, which leads to
many studies of closure properties of languages. It turns out that
closure properties are not independent, because many operations can be
defined by composition, or complex combinations, of other operations.

This has led to the study of what is usually called [Abstract Families
of Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages), i.e. families that are closed under the same kinds of
operations. But that is now far beyond your question.

Answer (score 3):

This notion is clalled **closure property**. A family $\mathcal F$ of languages is closed under (binary) operation $\#$ if $K\# L$ is in $\mathcal F$ for all $K,L$ in $\mathcal F$.

There are no general rules: context-free $\mathsf{CF}$ is closed under union $\cup$, deterministic context-free $\mathsf{DCF}$ is not. However there are resources that list the known closure properties for important families, especially the Chomsy hierarchy.

Comment: I asked for something like the "closure property" between two different language types. As I understand, the closure propery in the chomsky hierarchy doesn't tell me anything about the union between different language types. I'm looking for a rule like that:
The intersection of two context-free languages is NOT context-free (closure property for intersection), but it is context-sensitive (go 1 step down in the hierarchy and check the closure property of the context-sensitive languages).
Do you know any resoures that list the closure properties between different language families?